# Magento - Import/export custom options

Tags: import, magento-1.7

by default in Magento, it is not possible to export a products' csv file containing the custom options. Each product on our site contains tons on custom options and we need to upload from scratch 400 products. Anyone has a non-commercial solution for this or can point me in the right direction? Do I need to create a custom Dataflow?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

did you check out MAGMI? This is great and free importing tool for Magento, supports products custom options as well. Check out [this cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOC3MxA5YaLdFFwTk9uY2RQbmthQmZZdmVYZ3FUOEE&usp=drive_web#gid=5) for getting an idea how your CSV must look like. The format is like following (first line is CSV header defining the parameters of your custom optinos - label:type:flag whether is required option:position)

```
Size:drop_down:1:2                  Design:file:0:1                                 
Small|Medium:fixed:5|Large:fixed:10 Design image file:fixed:0:Ref file::jpg,png:500:300                                 
XS:percent:5|S:fixed:5|M|L|XL       Design image file:fixed:0:Ref file::txt:500:300
```

Comment: Good stuff, but do you have any insights on product options export?